# UV Sync Selection button doesn't appear (Stl file)

Tags: uv

So I've imported an stl file into Blender, everything works fine. However, when I select my object and go to UV Editing mode, the UV Sync Selection button doesn't appear!
I've tried the same steps with a regular .blend file and in that scenario I can see the UV Sync Selection button.
Is it a problem with stl files? What should I do? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Does you mesh *have* a UV map? Right dropdown, just below "shape keys"...

Comment: @JachymMichal I guess that's it. My screenshot took too long  ;)

Comment: @JachymMichal No indeed I don't! Do you have a good tutorial to recommend on how to create one? This tutorial from Blender only shows how to do it with a blender object (cube) so there is already a map... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM

Comment: Hey :). Simply going *UV > Smart UV Project* will give you an automatic one. As beginner friendly tutorials go, [BlenderGuru's anvil is a good one](https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k)

Comment: Thank you do much for your help @JachymMichal! I'll check the material you recommend :-)

Answer (score 2):

When the object has no UV map (see in the *Object Data Properties*) then there are no UVs to sync.

To get a UV map, hit <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap the object or at least the Plus-button next to the UV slots to add one.

[image]